# How do I make a picker view populate from an array of NSStrings? How would I then access the value of the item picked?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Okay, I need a picker so that a user can select from a list of predefined options.  Can someone give me the easy, simplified version of how to populate a picker view from an array of NSStrings?  Then, how do I read that value from the picker?  I'm noticing that things like nameOfPicker.value and nameOfPicker.text do not work here.

Thank you!

I have already read the following documents and I don't really understand what they are getting at.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIPickerView.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite similar to how you populate data in a `UITableView`, by setting datasource and delegate.

**1.** First step is to set the delegate of the picker view. In `.m` file you set your datasource and delegate

```
@interface YourViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *yourPickerView;
```

**2.** Assign the datasource and delegate

```
self.yourPickerView.delegate = self;
self.yourPickerView.datasource = self;
```

**3.** Implement datasource and delegate

```
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}
// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return self.yourArrayofStrings.count;
}

//The title that should be shown in picker view
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSString *yourTitle = [self.yourArrayofStrings objectAtIndex:row]

    return yourTitle;
}


//This is called when Picker view value is selected
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog @(@"Selected row = %@",[self.yourArrayofStrings objectAtIndex:row]);
}
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thank you so much for explaining what no one else seems to be able to.  :)

Comment: @user3361944, No problems! Glad to help